# How I can update multiple rows mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this datatable:

```
    id, surname, name;
    1, Ivanov, Ivan;
    2, Petrov, Petr;
    3, Sidorov, Sidr;
```

I want to change: Ivan to Ivan111, Petr to Petr222, Sidr to Sidr333.

How I can do this in one query? something like:

```
`UPDATE datatable SET name='Ivan111', name='Petr222', name=Sidr333' WHERE id=1, id=2, id=3`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` statement to perform conditional update

```
UPDATE datatable 
SET name= CASE  WHEN  id=1 THEN 'Ivan111'
                WHEN  id=2 THEN 'Petr222'
                WHEN  id=3 THEN 'Sidr333'
                ELSE  name 
          END
```

or if you want to concatenate id part 3 times with name for all records you can do it like

[For select](http://rextester.com/KHBHGA91474)

```
select id, surname, concat(name,repeat(id, 3)) as name from datatable
```

[For update](http://rextester.com/JNYL31364)

```
update datatable set name = concat(name,repeat(id, 3)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

update datatable  set name = CONCAT（name,id,id）